# Image doesn't fit on mobile screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image, responsive-design

I recently started building sites with bootstrap and ran into a problem while creating http://en.arecotechnology.com/gunassembly.html

When the screen is minimized, the photo does not fit on the screen. The same goes for other pages on the site, including http://en.arecotechnology.com/spe2018.html (The image overlays the text when the screen is minimized)

I tried playing around with the div but nothing seems to be working.

If someone can give me a hint as to what I should do, it'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 404 on both links. Add relevant code here since links rot.

Comment: Yes, I second that. Add code and/or make a replicate of the problem using jsfiddle. Also, if any of the answers below have worked, please consider accepting the answer as the correct answer.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for letting me know! The correct links are http://en.arecotechnology.com/gunassembly.html and http://en.arecotechnology.com/spe2018.html

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe changing the width so that it's 80%. That way it will always be at most, 80% of the screen width.

All I can provide with the given information. The links are dead, 404, same as Fecosos^^^

Try this too with media rules:

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {  
    .cupcake img {
        width: [insert desired with here for certain size];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make `<img>` take the maximum width of the parent add the class `img-responsive` (Bootstrap 3) or `img-fluid` (Bootstrap 4) to the images.

`<img class="img-fuid img-responsive" src="/images/my-image.jpg">`

img-responsive and img-fluid is a Boostrap utility that adds `max-width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` to the image. With this 2 properties you cover the majority of images problems, not allowing images to be wider that its container. Check Bootstrap's documentation, it has lots of helpful classes.

And add some media queries or again use bootstrap media queries helpers.

Comment: I gave it a try and it didn't seem to work: http://en.arecotechnology.com/propellantcaps.html (tried it with this page since most of my pages are experiencing the same problems) Wondering if I did it correctly? Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Try this **without** using a media query in your css file or style tags:

```
   img {
     max-width: 100%;
   }
```

In theory this should work because it becomes 100% of the screen size (not 100% actual size). So the max width will just stretch to 100% of screen size instead of scrolling off.

You might need to include other css, but this code is used widely for bootstrap-based sites in conjuction with other properties.

Comment: If the property `height: auto;`  is not added with images with `max-width: 100%;` images will be out of proportion. That's why in my answer I included both.